# Capturing the Image from camera intent image is rotating in some devices Android

Tags: java, android

I was trying to upload a profile of the user. In the app, users can choose from a gallery or camera.

While I was capturing the image from the camera, the image is rotating. I tried with exifinterface but the orientation getting as 0, and it works fine on some devices. How to solve this issue can anyone help me out?

*xml*

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    app:placeholderImage="@drawable/defaultprofile1"
    app:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
    app:roundingBorderColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
    fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

*Code*

```
draweeView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), new
                            String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            selectImage();
        }
    }
});

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Upload Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);

            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (data != null) {
                Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                System.out.println("imagebitmap" + selectedImage);
                Uri tempUri = getImageUri(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), selectedImage);
                System.out.println("tempUri" + tempUri);
                String picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);
                System.out.println("paaaaaaaa" + picturePath);
                File f = new File(picturePath);
                String imageName = f.getName();
                System.out.println("file f" + f);
                Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(picturePath));// For files on device
                draweeView3.setImageURI(imageUri);

            }
        }
    }
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    Bitmap OutImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, 1000, 1000, true);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), OutImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String path = "";
    if (getActivity().getContentResolver() != null) {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(idx);

            System.out.println("final path" + path);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post two intent actions and two blocks of code in onactivityresult. Stick to one. Dont confuse us. You can remove the permission code too.

Comment: @blackapps I have updated the coe

Comment: You are still requesting permissions. Please remove. `Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` That will give you only a thumbnail of the image. Not the full image. You realize that? And you get a bitmap and bitmaps do not contain exifinfo or orientation info so you are out of luck if you use this thumbnail.

Comment: ok I didnt know that it get the thumbnail. Then what was the solution.The Image is saving in my phone as landscape

Comment: You should add an uri for a file to your intent so the camera app can use that uri to save the image to. This is all pretty standard and you can find code everywhere. Once you have a real file you can use ExifInterface on the same uri for that file to extract orientation information. Do not use bad code like getRealPathForUri. You do not need that. You probably use a Samsung device.